# how to accommodate divs using percentages, does not fit perfectly

Tags: css

I am trying to accommodate my web page as you can see in this image. I'm not very good at CSS, but I did my best. especially I am not able to place the div3 where it corresponds, it moves downwards. what am I doing wrong?

[image]

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
}

.div2_container {
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 70%;
}

.div2_son {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
}

.div3 {
  display: inline;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">

  </div>

  <div class="div2_container">
    <div class="div2_son">

    </div>
    <div class="div2_son">

    </div>
    <div class="div2_son">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="div3">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: hey, please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Update my answer since you can't / don't want to use vieoport units. Actually the "problem" was your borders (fixed that using the calc() method).

So i kept your HTML structure and just update little bit the CSS like that:

```
<style>
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; /* this is for loosing browser initial margin */
  overflow-y: hidden; /* this is for disable the scroll, since 100% height is automatically add scroll */
}

.container {
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div1 {
  width: calc(70% - 2px);
  height: calc(50% - 2px);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.div2_container {
  width: calc(70% - 2px);
  height: calc(50% - 2px);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.div2_son {
  width: calc(33.33% - 2px); /* change width to fit the width */
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  /* display: inline-block; since we use float this is unnecessary */
  float: left; /* add that for putting it next to each other */
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.div3 {
  width: calc(30% - 2px);
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid brown;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2_container">
        <div class="div2_son"></div>
        <div class="div2_son"></div>
        <div class="div2_son"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Here you will find info about calc() function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Good luck!

Comment: thanks but I need use %. Can I use calc() using percents? . your code not works for me :(

Comment: @yavg i update my answer, hope it what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

try this...
change div1 and div 2 container `float:left` and div 3 `display: inline-block;`

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;

}

.div1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
  float:left
}

.div2_container {
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 70%;
  float:left
}

.div2_son {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
}

.div3 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 29%;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">

  </div>

  <div class="div2_container">
    <div class="div2_son">

    </div>
    <div class="div2_son">

    </div>
    <div class="div2_son">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="div3">

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added two more containers a left side and right side like so

```
<div class="container" >
  <div class="left">


    <div class="div1">
      Div 1
    </div>
    <div class="div2_container">
    <div class="div2_son">
      div 2
    </div>
    <div class="div2_son">
      div 2
    </div> 
    <div class="div2_son">
      div 2
    </div>       
  </div>

  </div> 
  <div class="right">
    <div class="div3">
    Div 3
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

and then by adding some floats we on the .left and .right containers we get them side by side after tweaking some of their widths. Then we can add some floats to .div2_son containers as well and tweak the widths to get them as precise as we can.

```
body,html{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.container{

    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.div1{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100%;
    height: 50%;
}

.div2_container{
  display: inline-block;
    height:49%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
}
.div2_son{
    float: left;
    width:32.8%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    height:100%
}

.div3{

    height: 99.8%;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid brown;
}



  .left {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width:70%;
    height: 100%;

  }
  .right {
    float: right;
    width:29.5%;

    height: 100%;
  }
```